ASP.NET Core WebAPI does not return ProblemDetails JSON when model binder validation fails
I am working on changes to an ASP.NET Core WebAPI application that has been upgraded to .NET 8. We make use of the ProblemDetails responses documented here:

Handle errors in ASP.NET Core - Problem Details

This is working fine except for validation failures which emit 400 Bad Request responses when the model binder fails to validate request parameters. For example, the following endpoint takes a DateTime parameter as a query string parameter:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("stacktest")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> StackTest([FromQuery] DateTime? date)
  {
    Return Ok();
  }
}

If I request this endpoint and provide an invalid date, for example:

http://localhost:5000/MyController/stacktest?date=not-a-valid-date

As expected the model binder automatically fails the validation and returns a 400 Bad Request response but it does not emit the expected ProblemDetails response JSON, e.g. this is what I expected:
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc9110#section-15.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "errors": {
    "date": [
      "The value 'not-a-valid-date' is not valid."
    ]
  },
  "traceId": "00-e2af23b124e37dcec4b2b5d72bca409d-705df282ff1dabe4-00"
}

What I got instead was a raw string with the validation error message i.e.

The value 'not-a-valid-date' is not valid.

I made sure that I enabled the Problem Details feature in my Startup.cs. As I mentioned earlier this is an older application that's been upgraded over time to .NET and still uses the older style of initialising the app using Program.cs and Startup.cs etc:
public class Startup
{
  private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

  public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
  {
    Configuration = configuration;
  }

  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services.AddProblemDetails();
  }
}

To confirm that the model binder should in fact emit a ProblemDetails json response, I created a simple .NET8 ASP.NET Core Web API project using the same code and configuration as above and it does emit the expected ProblemDetails json response for a 400 Bad Request.
So the question is, why isn't my older application (but now upgraded to .NET8) emitting a ProblemDetails json response when model binding validation fails?

Looking at your code snippet, it appears you've only registered the service without including the necessary middleware. To properly format the error, you need to add the middleware using the app.UseExceptionHandler() method.
For an implementation example, I recommend checking this repository:
https://github.com/irimescucosmin/ExceptionsHandler.NET

Thanks for your answer, I don't have time to address it at the moment, but just wanted you to know it's been seen.
